# Can you add parameters inside a print() function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to add parameters on a print function, because I have to print only the table and when I alert the table it shows me the correct value but when I'm printing it prints the entire page.

My code is

```
aa = document.getElementById('tablename').innerHTML
```

If I `alert(aa)` it gives me the write value
then I `print(aa)` it give me the entire page.
so I tried `print(aa)` and `aa.print` and it doesn't work.

Does anyone know the solution for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Print stylesheets are nice, but you can still accomplish this in Javascript.  Just pass your value to be printed to the following function...

```
function printIt(printThis) {
  var win = window.open();
  self.focus();
  win.document.open();
  win.document.write('<'+'html'+'><'+'body'+'>');
  win.document.write(printThis);
  win.document.write('<'+'/body'+'><'+'/html'+'>');
  win.document.close();
  win.print();
  win.close();
}
```

Comment: WebSocket connections don't work that was open in the parent window

Answer (score 6):

Define a print stylesheet which will only display the table.

- http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml
- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

There's no need for it to be dynamic.

Simply define those sections you don't wan to see as display:none (as stated in the alistapart article)

Comment: There might be a need for it to be dynamic - it depends if that is the one and only view of the page that will ever be printed.

Comment: Generally speaking I'd consider this a bad sign, maybe a sloppy design. It should be that you're just hiding menus and sometimes ads (I wish anyway). All the other stuff, people generally keep in a print out (headers, footers to retain copyrights and branding)

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve your requested functionality with tabular view in PDF as below, in my case I have given table id="tableId" then replaced that page data with Table which we need:

```
printTarget(tableId) {
    let divToPrint = document.getElementById('tableId');
    let htmlToPrint = 
        '<style type="text/css">' + 
        'table {'+'font-family: arial, sans-serif;'+ 
        'border-collapse: collapse;'+'width: 95%;'+ 
        'margin-left: 20px'+'}'+   
        'th, td {' +
        'border:1px solid #000;' +
        'padding: 8px;' +
        '}'+ 'tr:nth-child(even) {'+
        'background-color: #dddddd;'+'}'+
        '</style>';
    htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
    let windowToPrint = window.open("");    
    windowToPrint.document.write(htmlToPrint);
    windowToPrint.print();
    windowToPrint.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

What you could do is dynamically modify a print media stylesheet and display: none the elements you do not want.

[YUI StyleSheet](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/stylesheet/) might help with that.

Comment: The link is dead.