# Printing (*.rdlc) file with window.print() function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, printing, reporting

I am trying to print a edited **Report.rdlc** file with a datasource. There is not a problem about this report file. But, I couldn't give file name as parameter of the `window.print()` function. Is there a solution giving parameter in `window.print()` function or a working script. Even a text file as a parameter works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass the parameter to window.print function.but you can use below method to print only the part of page you need.

```
    function printIt(printThis) {
      var win = window.open();
      var dv=document.getElementById("printThis");
      self.focus();
      win.document.open();
      win.document.write('<'+'html'+'><'+'body'+'>');
      win.document.write(dv.innerHTML);
      win.document.write('<'+'/body'+'><'+'/html'+'>');
      win.document.close();
      win.print();
      win.close();
    }
```

check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887340/can-you-add-parameters-inside-a-print-function-in-javascript)

Comment: I hope for editing the .rdlc file you must be rendering it somehow.suppose if your .rdlc file is inside a div then pass the div id as the parameter to the above function

Comment: what does self.focus(); do here ?